# Time series insight API returning Could not cast or convert from System.String to Microsoft.Rdx.Client.Events.Property

Tags: azure, time-series, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-timeseries-insights

Hi we have just started using time series insight .We need to list specified  list of values of properties under particular Time series id    .As per the documentation in azure we were  using the following API   in post method to achieve  this .

> https://XXXXX_EnvironmentFqdn_XXXXX.env.timeseries.azure.com/timeseries/query?api-version=2018-11-01-preview

When posting the following request body to the API

```
        {
          "getEvents":{
             "timeSeriesId": ["UniqueId"],
            "searchSpan": {
               "from": "2019-02-17T00:00:00Z",
              "to": "2019-02-18T00:16:50Z"
              },
             "projectedProperties": ["DesiredProp"]
          }
        }
```

it returns  a 400 Bad Request with  following error message.

```
   {
    "error": {
    "code": "InvalidInput",
    "message": "Error converting value \"DesiredProp\" to type
    'Microsoft.Rdx.Client.Events.Property'. Path 
   'getEvents.projectedProperties[0]', line 9, position 45.\r\n---> Could 
    not        cast or convert from System.String to 
    Microsoft.Rdx.Client.Events.Property.\r\n"
      }
     }
```

on removing the projectedProperties property from  response body  API works fine,but it will return all the properties of the time series .

any help will me much appreciated and thanks in advance .